# why the path of figure shows out?

Tags: graphics

the package I use is `{graphicx}`.
and the code is following:

```
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{/Users/Joy/Desktop/my graph/SSE Ari&Geo.png}
```

How can I delete the address of picture under the graph?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: Welcome. It would be easier for us to help you if you included a full minimal file (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) that showed the problem (this is called an MWE here).  I've edited your post to use code highlighting: backticks(\`) can be used for short snippets of code and longer sections can be indented with 4 spaces.

Comment: Full minimal example please. However given the printed text matches a break at the space in the folder to the graph, you might want to have a look at the `grffile` package. You might also want to place that figure in the same folder as your `.tex` file, or in a subfolder instead of using a global path.

Comment: This may have something to do with the spaces and `&` signs in the path (as you only have a partial path), but in that case I would expect the figure to fail to import.  Otherwise I suggest a package option is to blame, hence why I recommend a full MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you place the image in the same folder as your .tex file and then just input the filename without the extension (it's not necessary). Like

```
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{SSE Ari&Geo}
```

The `&` causing errors is inconsistent (it seems to throw the error when there is a space in the filename though). In any case, I'd suggest removing it to avoid any conflicts. Renaming the file to a simple "AriGeo" will do.

Comment: I tried to put image in the same folder as my .tex file and I delete the "&" and the space between SSE and AriGeo, problem solved. Thank you.